# How can show the keypoints from the JSON file?

Tags: python, json, opencv, matplotlib

```
IMG_DIR = '/Dataset/*.png'
JSON = '/JSON/json.json'
```

```
with open('JSON/json.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print(data)
```

```
{'_via_settings': {'ui': {'annotation_editor_height': 25, 'annotation_editor_fontsize': 0.8, 'leftsidebar_width': 18, 'image_grid': {'img_height': 80, 'rshape_fill': 'none', 'rshape_fill_opacity': 0.3, 'rshape_stroke': 'yellow', 'rshape_stroke_width': 2, 'show_region_shape': True, 'show_image_policy': 'all'}, 'image': {'region_label': '__via_region_id__', 'region_color': '__via_default_region_color__', 'region_label_font': '10px Sans', 'on_image_annotation_editor_placement': 'NEAR_REGION'}}, 'core': {'buffer_size': 18, 'filepath': {}, 'default_filepath': ''}, 'project': {'name': 'via_project_12Jan2023_11h22m'}}, '_via_img_metadata': {'512_512_imran20200801_170919.png848': {'filename': '512_512_imran20200801_170919.png', 'size': 848, 'regions': [], 'file_attributes': {}}, '512_1024_eduart_5493.png1472': {'filename': '512_1024_eduart_5493.png', 'size': 1472, 'regions': [], 'file_attributes': {}}, '512_1024_eduart_5840.png2300': {'filename': '512_1024_eduart_5840.png', 'size': 2300, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 409, 'cy': 120}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 356, 'cy': 403}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 360, 'cy': 476}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '512_1024_eduart_420210722_170544.png1850': {'filename': '512_1024_eduart_420210722_170544.png', 'size': 1850, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 69, 'cy': 43}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 194, 'cy': 49}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 176, 'cy': 222}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 350, 'cy': 240}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 506, 'cy': 188}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '512_2048_eduart_5702.png2076': {'filename': '512_2048_eduart_5702.png', 'size': 2076, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 336, 'cy': 51}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 201, 'cy': 421}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '512_2560_eduart_5extra_35.png1905': {'filename': '512_2560_eduart_5extra_35.png', 'size': 1905, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 349, 'cy': 295}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 495, 'cy': 24}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '512_2560_evgenii_Ext_120201005_142724.png1390': {'filename': '512_2560_evgenii_Ext_120201005_142724.png', 'size': 1390, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 393, 'cy': 212}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 435, 'cy': 169}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '1024_2048_eduart_420210919_151508.png1218': {'filename': '1024_2048_eduart_420210919_151508.png', 'size': 1218, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 37, 'cy': 466}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 327, 'cy': 439}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 431, 'cy': 454}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 499, 'cy': 451}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '1536_1024_imranparkhaus_rub_32.png1016': {'filename': '1536_1024_imranparkhaus_rub_32.png', 'size': 1016, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 235, 'cy': 428}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '1536_1536_eduart_5642.png1076': {'filename': '1536_1536_eduart_5642.png', 'size': 1076, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 152, 'cy': 436}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '1536_2560_evgenii_NL_3_120200916_154505.png1609': {'filename': '1536_2560_evgenii_NL_3_120200916_154505.png', 'size': 1609, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 51, 'cy': 399}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 458, 'cy': 104}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '2048_1024_imran20200801_171936.png1101': {'filename': '2048_1024_imran20200801_171936.png', 'size': 1101, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 298, 'cy': 411}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '2048_1024_imran20200801_184730.png870': {'filename': '2048_1024_imran20200801_184730.png', 'size': 870, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 481, 'cy': 451}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}, '2048_1536_imran20200801_171936.png1243': {'filename': '2048_1536_imran20200801_171936.png', 'size': 1243, 'regions': [{'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 4, 'cy': 354}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 169, 'cy': 344}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 321, 'cy': 270}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}, {'shape_attributes': {'name': 'point', 'cx': 396, 'cy': 241}, 'region_attributes': {'keypoints': 'keypoints'}}], 'file_attributes': {}}}, '_via_attributes': {'region': {'keypoints': {'type': 'text', 'description': '', 'default_value': ''}}, 'file': {}}}
```

```
with open('/JSON/json.json') as json_file:
    json_string = json_file.read()
    data = json.loads(json_string)
    print(type(data))
```

```
<class 'dict'>
```

How can show the key points of the JSON data? I just need to show I mean visualize the key points from the JSON.

Comment: what do you mean by key points here?

Comment: keypoint detection